# vm_service is pinned to version 13.0.0 by flutter_test from the flutter SDK

Tags: flutter

I updated my `flutter SDK` to the latest major version, but now `pub get` is not working for me anymore, please how do I resolve this

```
Resolving dependencies...
Note: vm_service is pinned to version 13.0.0 by flutter_test from the flutter SDK.
See https://dart.dev/go/sdk-version-pinning for details.


    Because riverpod_lint ^1.3.2 depends on custom_lint_builder ^0.4.0 and no versions of custom_lint_builder match >0.4.0 <0.5.0, riverpod_lint ^1.3.2 requires custom_lint_builder 0.4.0.
(1) So, because custom_lint_builder 0.4.0 depends on hotreloader ^3.0.5, riverpod_lint ^1.3.2 requires hotreloader ^3.0.5.

    Because no versions of hotreloader match >3.0.6 <4.0.0 and hotreloader >=3.0.5 <3.0.6 depends on vm_service >=6.0.1 <10.0.0, hotreloader >=3.0.5 <3.0.6-∞ or >3.0.6 <4.0.0 requires vm_service >=6.0.1 <10.0.0.
    And because hotreloader 3.0.6 depends on vm_service >=6.0.1 <12.0.0, hotreloader ^3.0.5 requires vm_service >=6.0.1 <12.0.0.
    And because riverpod_lint ^1.3.2 requires hotreloader ^3.0.5 (1), riverpod_lint ^1.3.2 requires vm_service >=6.0.1 <12.0.0.
    And because every version of flutter_test from sdk depends on vm_service 13.0.0, riverpod_lint ^1.3.2 is incompatible with flutter_test from sdk.
    So, because prayer_buddy depends on both flutter_test from sdk and riverpod_lint ^1.3.2, version solving failed.


You can try the following suggestion to make the pubspec resolve:
* Try an upgrade of your constraints: flutter pub upgrade --major-versions
```

**What i have done so far**

1. I have run `flutter clean`
2. i have run `invalidated/clean cache`
3. i have deleted the `pubspec.lock`
4. I have restared the system,

Yet issues still persists